# Structure of a set whose image through continuous convex functions is an interval

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

What can be said about a subset $S$ of a Banach space $X$ with the property that $f(S)$ is an interval, for every convex lower semi-continuous function $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ that has at least one continuity point (equivalently the domain of $f$ has a non-empty interior) and such that $S$ is a subset of the domain of $f$?

For example if $S$ is connected then $f(S)$ is an interval whenever $f$ is convex defined everywhere because in this case $f$ is continuous. So I expected something similar for the general question.

Comment: Do you really mean that $f(S)$ must be an interval for _every_ c.l.s.c $f\colon X\longrightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$? Because this seems like a very strong condition...

Comment: Yes, every lsc convex function that is continuous on the interior of their domains. If it make things easier you can take all continuous convex functions defined on the whole space. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into any particularly deep analysis, here are my thoughts: (let's assume, like you say, for simplicity we run over all convex $f$s that are continuous and defined on all of $X$)

First I would start with thinking about what it would mean for $f(S)$ to *not* be an interval: this means there is some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ that "separates" $f(S)$ (i.e., $x\not\in f(S)$ but there exist $a<x<b$ with $a,b\in f(S)$). Thus, the *level set* $f^{-1}(x)$ is obviously disjoint from $S$ (is $f^{-1}(x)$ unbounded?). Thus for the $S$ to have the desired property, it cannot be separated by the level set of any such $f$. Obviously like you said if $S$ is connected then obviously cannot be separated by any such level set.

Second, to get your hands on what this really means, I would think about how to prove/generalize the following pictures: set $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, and this is the picture of what I was describing.
[image]
EDIT: Let me explain the figure a little more: if a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be separated by the level set of a convex function, then we should be able to draw what looks like the graph of a convex function $\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ separating the graph.

Comment: Actually I reached at that formulation from a more general property applied for the level sets of a continuous convex function. It's the other problem I had a bounty for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514768/segment-ordered-density-conjecture-revisited