# Segment ordered density conjecture revisited

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a set $S\subset\mathbb {R}^2$ with the following property

(P) $\forall x,y\in S$, $\forall\mathscr{C}$ a convex set that contains $x$ in its interior, $bd\mathscr{C}\cap [x,y]\subset \overline{bd\mathscr{C}\cap S}$.

Here $[x,y]$ denotes the segment with end-ponts $x$, $y$, $\ bd\mathscr{C}$ denotes the boundary of $\mathscr{C}$, and "$\overline{\ \ \ \ \ }$" stands for closure.

In other words the inclusion says

$\forall z\in bd\mathscr{C},\ z=tx+(1-t)y$, for some $0<t<1$, there is $(z_n)_n\subset bd\mathscr{C}\cap S,\ z_n\to z$.

This feels like $S$ is dense in an orderly fashion in the segment $[x,y]$ (on every boundary of a convex set).

I can prove that $\overline{S}$ is convex. Also, note that (P) is a local property, that is, if $S$ has (P) then so does $S\cap V$ where $V$ is an open convex set.

My question is:

What else can be said about a subset $S$ with the above property? Is it locally connected?